# using space when ad is not loaded android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob

I am trying to add admob ads in my application but when I am not connected to internet than too empty space is there...

I want add to appear after loading until then ad space should be utilized by the rest elements

what to do???

My Activity file is given below -

**MainActivity.java**
`

```
package com.testapp.update1;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private AdView adView;
GridView grid;
String[] icons = { "Historic Places", "Railway", "City Bus", "Movie",
        "Directory" };

int[] imageID = { R.drawable.ic_historic, R.drawable.ic_train,
        R.drawable.ic_bus, R.drawable.ic_movie, R.drawable.ic_call };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //adding advertisement 
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(CommanData.AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    layout.addView(adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                                .addTestDevice("4963BE445DBBB277")
                                .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, icons, imageID);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.icongrid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "You clicked at " + icons[position] + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent web = new Intent();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                web.setClass(MainActivity.this, Places.class);
                startActivity(web);
                break;
            case 1:
                web.setClass(MainActivity.this, Railway.class);
                startActivity(web);
                break;
            case 2:
                web.setClass(MainActivity.this, BusOptions.class);
                startActivity(web);
                break;
            case 3:
                ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                if(cd.isConnected()) {
                    web.setClass(MainActivity.this, Movies.class);
                    startActivity(web);
                } else {
                    showConnectivityDialog();
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        CallDirctory.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    // to load add
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // To rate application at google play
    // AppRater.showRateDialog(mContext, editor)
    AppRater.app_launched(MainActivity.this);
}

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.resume();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }


public void showConnectivityDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder notfoundDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    notfoundDialog.setTitle("Not Connected")
            .setMessage("It seems you are not connected to internet")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the visibility of

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
```

i.e. the layout to which you are adding your `Adview`to `View.GONE` initially so it will occup no space.

Now add an `AdListener` to the `AdView` and make the above mentioned layout `View.VISIBLE` in the `onAdLoaded`method of the `AdListener`. That way the layout will never be visible until the `Ad` is loaded.

For eg.

```
AdListener googleAdListener = new AdListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded()
    {
        super.onAdLoaded();
        try
        {
            (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.LogException(e);
        }
    }
};

adView.setAdListener(googleAdListener);
```

**NOTE:** You will have to use the latest `google-play-services-lib` not `AdMobsSDK`

Comment: Is the layout containing `AdView` the only child of any layout?

Comment: layout is parent layout ie main container

Comment: Can you post your layout?

Comment: Thanks @Apoorv you code is really helpful just little change for my scenario made it work

Answer (score 2):

Just do like this for displaying ads, overcome the blank space when no internet connection -->

```
//In your activity //
```

ADDING Admob ADs

```
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(" xxx").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    //
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

In activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:background="#FBAC4F"
    ads:adUnitId="xxx"
    android:visibility="gone"

    />
```

Surely it will help all developers.