# Know when ads are loaded?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, optimization, methods

## Is there a way to see if the ads in the **next** activity are loaded yet?

For example, if I am on `Activity A`, and there are ads on `Activity B`, I will switch from `A -> B` **only** when the ads of `Activity B` are **done** loading. **Is there some sort of listener I can use to check whether the ads are loaded?**

I know about this method:

```
 AdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
     // Implement AdListener
 });
```

But that will work only if the add is in the activity using that method in. So, is it even possible?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337165/using-space-when-ad-is-not-loaded-android

Comment: @IrinaAvram Again, as I stated in the question, _But that will work only if the add is in the activity using that method in_. That question's answer suggest adding that code in every activity. Therefor, that question is invalid, and blatantly unrelated to this question. If you have any suggestions, feel free to answer. But, again, that question is nothing like this one, as I even mentioned that method in the question.

Comment: yeah, using fragments instead of activities

Comment: @IrinaAvram How? Feel free to write an answer.